# Is there a way to add color of yhat on 3D partial plot with pdp

Tags: r, plot, random-forest

I produced 3D partial plot with `pdp` package like this:

```
partial1 <- pdp::partial(rf_full, pred.var = c("Long", "Lat"),
                         parallel = T, paropts =list(.packages = "randomForest"))
p2 <- plotPartial(partial1, levelplot = F, colorkey = T, plot.pdp = T)
```

However, the color of the target variable (yhat) **1)** doesn't fill the grid cells and **2)** seems to be always the same color (for high values of yhat). It looks as follow:
[image]

Do you have any idea how to obtain something like this for instance:

[image]

Comment: Can please you post a complete [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try plotting using the following option `drape=T`, which is an option of `wireframe`:

```
plotPartial(partial1, levelplot = F, colorkey = F, plot.pdp = F, drape=T)
```

Comment: Oh wow, it seems to work. Just, do you know why we must specify `colorkey = F`, it seems counter intuitive.. Same for the other argument `plot.pdp = F`, it's really the opposite of what I would write ^^`

Comment: @FrsLry No, I just looked through the documentation and searched for the option that you need. If my answer solves your problem, please accept it using the green checkmark.